# Uploading app to iTunes Store,Error in Mavericks OSX 10.9.3 ,Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, itunes, osx-mavericks

I have recently uploaded my app to appstore but while uploading an Updated version I got this error in Xcode (5.1.1) and Application Loader(2.9.1) in Mavericks(10.9.3)

[image: 'Error occurred uploading to iTunes Store'.]

I read about moving Java files - My current version of Java shows 1.6.0_65,
firewall off, re-downloading distribution profiles and I did so. But none seems working. Where is the problem?

Comment: Hello @nitin there are answers regarding OS 10.8, I am running Mavericks-10.9 thats why I have specified it in Heading!

Comment: check : https://www.google.co.in/search?q=an+error+occored++uploading++o+the+appstore&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=YQCcU6-JKIbFoAPj74KgDw#channel=fflb&q=an+error+occurred+uploading+to+the+app+store+xcode5.1&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&safe=active